# Getting field datatypes from a SQL Analysis Services MDX SELECT query using .NET AdomdClient

Tags: .net, ssas, adomd.net

Let's say I have this MDX query against SQL Server's Analysis Service Adventure Works sample:

```sql
select [Measures].[Customer Count] on columns, 
[Date].[Calendar Quarter of Year] on rows
from [Adventure Works]
```

And I execute it as:

```cs
var reader = new AdomdCommand("...").ExecuteReader();
```

I would expect that

```cs
reader.GetFieldType(0);
```

would return System.Int32, but it returns System.Object.
The same is true if I query schema with `reader.GetSchemaTable()` which is no surprise as I assume the former gets data from later.
I also assume this is probably not an exclusive .NET issue. The same is at least true for .NET Framework.

So, is there a way I can get those types when I do a query?